# CSS custom cursor image - overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a custom cursor image that I'm using with a span inside a bootstrap anchor button. 
I'm trying to get overflow hidden to work so when the cursor is close to the edges of the button the image is cutoff like the attached pic.
I have a [codepen](http://codepen.io/tbuchanan/pen/egPZGd/) here that I'm working with. Can anyone help with this?

HTML:

```
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-spotlight" id="happyButton">
      <span class="spotlight">EXPLORE</span>
    </a>
```

SCSS:

```
    #happyButton {
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
      color: white;
      &:hover {
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      & .spotlight {
        cursor: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/happy.png") 5 12, auto;
        padding: 15px 30px;
      }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are not elements of the page, and thus can't be manipulated like that.

I'd say there's no *sane* way to accomplish this.